# How can I find all Python packages that no other packages depend on?

Tags: package-management, python, dependencies, uninstall, pip

Is there a way to list all Python packages that *no other packages* depend on?

I've tried [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/), which is nice to get dependency trees, but I'm not sure if this is a good starting point (although I can imagine that it should be somehow possible to hack the text output to extract this information). Also, I'm not sure if `pipdeptree` is not omitting any package that doesn't have dependencies.

Is there maybe some native functionality of `pip` that provides that?

Motivation: I want to delete all packages that have been installed at some point as dependencies, but are no longer in use. For a clean reinstall, one could use [`pip-autoremove`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-autoremove/) to uninstall all packages and reinstall only what's needed, but that would be too much hassle for me as this basically amounts to a complete reinstallation.

Comment: Please do not cross post with our brothers and sisters on stack ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not your sister